# open files, keeping folder structure as nested list

Tags: python, list

I have a folder with the following structure:

```
data
|-folder1
  |--subfolder1
     |--file1
     |--file2
  |--subfolder2
     |file1
     |file2
|-folder2
  |--subfolder1
     |--file1
     |--file2
  |--subfolder2
     |file1
     |file2
```

with many folders, subfolder and files.

How can i create a list that is subdivided into smaller lists that contain my data?
For example, I'd end up with a list called `data` and I could retrieve file1 from folder1-subfolder1 by indexing `data[0][0][0]`?
As of now, I have created empty lists for each file but I'm not sure on how to append to a list of lists.

I have:

```
file1 = []
file2 = []
for folder in sorted(os.listdir(path)):
    if folder != 'Documentation.txt':
        for subfolder in sorted(os.listdir(path + '/' + folder)):
            if subfolder != '.DS_Store':
                for file in sorted(os.listdir(path+ '/' + folder + '/' + subfolder)):
                    if file.endswith(".x.dat"):
                        file1.append(pd.read_csv((path + '/' + folder + '/' + subfolder + '/' + file), header=None, sep=' '))
                    if file.endswith(".y.dat"):
                        file2.append(pd.read_csv((path + '/' + folder + '/' + subfolder + '/' + file), header=None, sep=' '))
data = [file1, file2]
```

This returns all the data files, but I'm struggling to figure out how to nest each file in a list of list according to the original folder structure... I feel like the solution will be pretty trivial, i'm just not great with python. Thanks

Comment: What made you to desired output like that, you directly use os.walk wihout changes as that would be more efficent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following with [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/pathlib.html)'s [`Path.rglob()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob) and [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/itertools.html) (all standard library):

```
from pathlib import Path
from itertools import groupby
from functools import partial

def key(i, file): return file.parent.parts[i]

base = Path("data")
data = []
for _, group1 in groupby(base.rglob("*.dat"), key=partial(key, 1)):
    data.append([])
    for _, group2 in groupby(group1, key=partial(key, 2)):
        data[-1].append([file.name for file in group2])
```

With a test structure created by

```
base = Path("data")
for i in range(1, 4):
    for j in range(1, 3):
        path = (base / f"folder{i}") / f"subfolder{j}"
        path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        for k in range(1, 3):
            with open(path / f"file{i}-{j}-{k}.dat", "w") as file:
                file.write("A,B,C\n1,2,3\n4,5,6")
```

this delivers the following `data`:

```
[[['file1-1-1.dat', 'file1-1-2.dat'], ['file1-2-1.dat', 'file1-2-2.dat']],
 [['file2-1-1.dat', 'file2-1-2.dat'], ['file2-2-1.dat', 'file2-2-2.dat']],
 [['file3-1-1.dat', 'file3-1-2.dat'], ['file3-2-1.dat', 'file3-2-2.dat']]]
```

Your code implies that you actually don't want to collect the filenames but `pd.csv_read()` them and store the dataframes in `data`. To do that you have to replace

```
        data[-1].append([file.name for file in group2])
```

with

```
        data[-1].append([pd.read_csv(file) for file in group2])
```

And it might well be that you have to add more logic to the file selection: I just went with the `.dat` suffix.

You could do something similar with `os.walk` instead, as suggested in the other answer:

```
from pathlib import Path
from os import walk

base = "data"
data = []
for root, _, files in walk(base):
    if ".DS_Store" in root:
        continue
    num_parts = len(Path(root).parts)
    if num_parts == 2:
        data.append([])
    elif num_parts == 3:
        data[-1].append([file for file in files if file.endswith(".dat")])
```

resp.

```
       data[-1].append([pd.read_csv(Path(root) / file) for file in files])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what's the exact output you want, but I'm pretty sure `os.walk` is probably the best option for you to generate a tree of your files:

```
>>> import os
>>> import re
>>> data_path = '/Users/nilton/data'
>>> files_paths = []
>>> for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(data_path):
...     for filename in filenames:
...         if re.match('\.dat', filename, re.I):
...             files_paths.append(filename)
...
>>> files_paths
['/Users/nilton/data/folder2/subfolder2/file2.dat',
 '/Users/nilton/data/folder2/subfolder2/file1.dat',
 ...]
```

Knowing this and reading the `os.walk` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk), you can manage to get your desired output by playing with the 3-tuple `(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)` output from `os.walk`.

Comment: i've played around with os.walk. it's not really what i'm looking for. i'm already able to open the files (as per my code above), i want to be able to call the arrays based on their index (ie. which folder and subfolder they belong to), if that makes more sense

Comment: the output would be something like `[ [ [], [] ...], [ [] , [], ...], ...] `

Comment: Could you please put an example of the output you'd like to have?

Comment: i just did. the output is a twice nested list according to the folder structure

Comment: I saw your comment. By putting an example I mean your lists with data, something like: `[ [ ['folder1/subfolder2'], ['file1.dat'] ...], [ [] , [], ...], ...]`

Comment: sorry, i don't really know how to vocalize it. I have a folder with subfolders and in those subfolders there are files. I want to be able to make a list that when indexed i will get the data from the file. such that `data[0][0][0]` would return the array from file1 of subfolder1 of folder1, for example. i want to be able to index through all of the files while keeping the folder and subfolder structure

Comment: the list would be like `data[folder][subfolder][file]` and it's structure is like i posted above `[[ [[],[],...], [[],[],...], ...],...]`

Comment: `re.match('\.dat', filename, re.I)` won't work: `re.match` requires a match a the _beginning_ of the string (try `print(re.match('\.dat', 'file.dat', re.I))`).